# uSDaemon in Linino / Arduino Yun Mini hogging the syslog

Tags: arduino-yun

There is an annoying problem with Linino One / Arduino Yun Mini as the syslog (logread) is full of messages from uSDaemon, complaining about missing files.

**ls: /sys/bus/scsi/drivers/sd/*/block/sd?: No such file or directory

handle umount errors

check umount**

(and so on, three lines every two seconds, so every other meaningful information is pushed out of the syslog pretty soon)

If I disable the uSDaemon with
**/etc/init.d/usd disable** 

the syslog is OK, but is there any functionality actually lost if uSDaemon is not running, beside being unable to read from a non-existing uSD card reader?